# Linear relation between $_3F_2$ at $z=1$

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-functions

A colleague of mine found the following linear relation between values at
1 of the $_3F_2$ hypergeometric function using a very indirect argument. I am aware that there are myriads of such relations, but this one seems to be
of a new type. Any help on finding a direct proof (just out of curiosity)?

Let

$T_1= {}_3F_2(1,1,1;a,a;1)$ ,

$T_2= {}_3F_2(2,1,1;a+1,a+1;1)$ ,

$T_3= {}_3F_2(2a-1,1,1;a+1,a+1;1)$.

Then for $a>3/2$ we have
$$(2a-3)T_1+\dfrac{(a-1)^2}{a^2}(T_2-2(a-1)T_3)=\dfrac{\Gamma(a)^2}{\Gamma(2a-2)}$$

Comment: Numerically it seems OK.